# On the group action

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=P \ltimes Q$ be a non-nilpotent group, where $P \cong Q_8$ and $Q \cong \Bbb{Z}_q \times \Bbb{Z}_q$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. ($q \neq 2$, is a prime number). Let $z \in P$, $|z|=2$. If $[z,Q]=1$, then i want to know:

(i). $P/ \langle z \rangle$ acts on $Q$.

(ii) how we conclude from (i) that there exists some
element $x$ of $P$ of order $4$ acts as an automorphism of order $2$ on $Q$.

My work: I know $P/ \langle z \rangle \cong \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2$. Since $[z,Q]=1$, we have $z \in Z(G)$.

there exists a homomorphism $\varphi: P \longrightarrow {\rm Aut}(Q)$.

I think $P/ \langle z \rangle$ acts on $Q$ via:

$ \forall y \in Q, \forall a\langle z \rangle \in P/ \langle z \rangle, \ \ y^{a\langle z \rangle}:=y^a$, ($ a \in P$). Is it true?

Also i know since $[P,Q] \neq 1$. Thus ${\rm Ker}(\varphi)=C_P(Q) <P$. Clearly $z \in C_P(Q)$.
but i cant find relation between (i) & (ii).

Comment: Choose $x \in P \setminus C_P(Q)$. Then $x \not\in \langle z \rangle$, so $x$ has order $4$ and $x^2=z \in C_P(Q)$. So $x$ acts as an automorphism of order $2$ on $Q$. By the way, the situation you describe is actually impossible. It is not possible for $Q$ to be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ in this situation.

Comment: @ Derek Holt  $P/ \langle z \rangle$ acts on $Q$. my definition of this action is true?

Comment: what is the relation between (i)&(ii)?

Comment: Yes your definition of the action of $P/\langle z \rangle$ is correct.

Comment: @ Derek Holt thanks, i couldnt find.  the relation between (i)&(ii)? is there a relation?